# Copy atributes of a struct to another struct of the same type

Tags: c

I have a struct and I want to copy the elements in the outfname of orig to the outfname of dest. How can I do this?

```
typedef struct {
    char outfname[256];
} sudoku_t;

void sudoku_copy(sudoku_t* orig,sudoku_t* dest){
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
void sudoku_copy(sudoku_t* orig, sudoku_t* dest)
{
    *dest = *orig;
}
```

just use the assignment operator.

As a side-note I suggest you to use `dest` as the first parameter in your function to align with the C convention used by functions like `memcpy` and `strcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative (most portable) approach would be:

```
#include <string.h>

void sudoku_copy(sudoku_t* orig, sudoku_t* dest)
{
    memcpy(dest, orig, sizeof (*dest));
}
```